# How much data can I store in the SPIFFS memory of ESP32 Wroom?

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm saving sensor data on file and later uploading it to a server. I'm wondering what's the limit on how big the file can get and what would happen if i continued writing data to the file?

Comment: 1) this is not a question about software/programming. 2) you can find out how much you allocated to the SPIFFS from Tools -> Partition Scheme of your Arduino IDE.

Comment: Thanks I think that shows what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what the size of the SPIFFS partition is by clicking Tools > Partitioning Scheme in the Arduino IDE. You should also have a couple of options to select from.

You can also use a custom partition table if you want. More info [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html).

It must also be noted that the performance of SPIFFS will drop as it starts to get full. In my experience I have noticed that it works best when only 70-80% of it is used. I would recommend writing your own code to keep track of the memory usage. You can read more about that [here](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2718).